# libGdx how to return the camera rotation

Tags: java, libgdx

```
camera.rotate(1.5f);
```

I can rotate the camera with degrees like so, but how can I return the rotation of the current camera so for example I know how many degrees it takes so I can restore it back to the normal rotation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have dealt with the same problem and since the libgdx camera doesn't natively have a function for returning the rotation, solved it by creating a function returning the cameras rotation in degrees.

```
public float getCameraRotation()
{                       
     float camAngle = -(float)Math.atan2(camera.up.x, camera.up.y)*MathUtils.radiansToDegrees + 180;         
     return camAngle;
}
```

It works by getting the camera angle in radiant:

```
-(float)Math.atan2(camera.up.x, camera.up.y)
```

then converting it to degrees:

```
*MathUtils.radiansToDegrees
```

and finally since the range of the angle is -180 to 180 converting it to 0-360

```
+ 180
```